# IOS Swift how can I highlight a selected images

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using swift 4 and I have an app where people can upload images . My question is when I open the image gallery and a user selects an image I would like to highlight that image like how facebook does . I know it has to be in this function since every time someone selects an image this function is called ... I have actually been trying to figure this out but nothing has worked .

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
{


 }
```

Comment: If you are using default API like Image picker, its difficult to customize it. Better use 3rd party or your custom code to handle it as you want.

Comment: its not possible default picker you have to implement your picker using collectionview and `photos` framework

Answer (score 0):

If you are using default API like Image picker, its difficult to customize it. Better use 3rd party or your custom code to handle it as you want.